# Radius as a constant while deriving of formula for acceleration in circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-kinematics, differentiation

While deriving acceleration in circular motion, we differentiate $\vec{v}=\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}$
Here we differentiate by product rule and write $\frac{dr}{dt}$ as $v$.

So we know $\vec{s} =\vec{\theta} \vec{r}$ . For finding velocity we differentiate this. Here why do we keep $r$ constant?

Comment: In circular motion, $r$ is constant (as a circle has constant radius).

Comment: in your question, you say dr/dr = v.  Did you mean dr/dt = v?

Comment: Also, it's of note that $v=\omega r$ will not help you derive acceleration. You need $\vec{v}=\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}$. This is because $r$ (the magnitude of $\vec{r}$) is constant, but $\vec{r}$ is not.

Comment: What if we write vector s = vector theta × vector r . Then differentiate it to find velocity.

Comment: $\theta$ won't have a direction... I don't think it's a vector.

Comment: Angular displacement ie theta is a vector quantity

Comment: If this is your goal: "*deriving acceleration in **circular motion***", then the radius must be constant. Otherwise you wouldn't have a circular motion - maybe an elliptic motion or a spiral motion, but not a circular motion. And if you don't have a circular motion, then what you derive doesn't strictly apply for circular motion.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of **circular** motion is that the motion is in, well, a circle. Circles are defined as the set of all points a distance $R$ from a given point. You are correct, however, if $R$ is not a constant. In that case, your life gets a bit more complicated, as you would have to parametrize your curve.

Comment: I've edited the question. Have a look